# Can Angular's global styles injection into <head> impact performance?

Tags: angular, angular-cli

When following the Angular-cli documentation, all styles included as global-styles end up getting injected into the `<head>` of the document upon DOM creation. Considering that often global-styles can consist of many lines of code, I'm trying to understand if  injection is suitable for large, systematic-design webapps.

I can see the benefits of having styles in the `<head>` on first load. But what happens on subsequent loads? The browser does not cache inlined or `<head>` styles, which makes external CSS files a better choice: download once, load from cache from then on. Angular's approach leads to loading the styles (from JS effectively) on every new page load.

Or am I missing something? Perhaps because the `<head>` styles are rendered from JS, and since Angular's files are downloaded and cached themselves, the styles are in actuality cached too?

Comment: But won't the browser cache `index.html` itself?

Comment: Good point, but not sure at what point in the runtime the `index.html` gets cached. Also, the point of an external CSS file is that it can be used independently of the view loaded, so it should be cached already for pages other than `index.html`

Comment: I believe `index.html` gets cached just like any other file. As for pages other than index.html, there aren't any, right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Almost everything you said is true, that's why `angular-cli` has the  option to extract css into css files, instead of js

```
--extract-css (Boolean) Extract css from global styles onto css files instead of js ones.
  aliases: -ec, --extractCss
```

So you can use it like this:

```
ng build -ec
```

Comment: Ha! great. I missed that option in the documentation (I did look though :) ). That solves the dillema. Thanks!

Just to get the idea better: So given that the entire Angular app, including global styles, are being compiled to JS, does it mean that styles in effect DO get cached?

Comment: If you cache your JS files then you are also caching your css

Comment: Nice one. Thanks!